# After logging off, a user is able to see the pages by pressing back button of the browser

Tags: 7, caching, users

I have a requirement in which the user should not be able to see the books in the site unless he is logged in. And the user is not able to see the content.

The problem is when a user logs in, views a book and its child pages, and logs out; he is still able to view the pages he opened before when he was logged in, by pressing the back button of the browser. He is not able to make any changes though.

This may create problems when users visit the site from a public computer, log off, and go away without closing the browser window.

Is there a module or any setting change I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: There is a module in D7 named "bbr" Browser Back Button.

Comment: @YogeshKushwaha I see that you wrote the module recently! Good job for the same! Can you add the link and module excerpt as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a result of the browser caching the page, there's not a lot you can do about it really.

Some browsers might respond to setting cache control headers like the following:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

which might force the browser to re-load the page regardless of it's local cache.

There are apparently some [options available to control this in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297122/preventing-cache-on-back-button-in-safari-5/5305905#5305905) specifically, but I haven't been able to find anything for other browsers. I imagine the same would work for Chrome (being Webkit based), but I can't comment on the the other major browsers.

Comment: Upvoted for a good answer, but I doubt webkit has anything to with it. Webkit handles only layout, and I imagine doesn't care at all about HTTP headers.

Comment: @Letharion Do you mean that Webkit doesn't control any of the browser's navigation then and just handles layout? I was under the impression Webkit was the basis for the entire browser (not just the rendering engine), have I got that wrong? Oh by the way, the other post I linked to was a JS solution to the problem which is why I mentioned Webkit at all

Comment: I haven't examined the code, but I believe webkit is only a small part of most browsers using it. Wikipedia start with: "WebKit is a layout engine". Webkit's own website says under goals that it should be "a general-purpose display and interaction engine".

Comment: @Letharion So it does, I never knew that :p

Comment: I understand that it is the problem of browser caching the pages. But, I tested the same on IE 9 and it works absolutely fine. But, the problem was reported on Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.
I think disabling the caching might do the trick, but I don't want to do that.
please help..

Comment: @Ajit that's the point I was making...it's a client side browser issue, so there's nothing you can do. If that's how the browser wants to react then that's how it will react, you won't be able to control it

Comment: If you have seen the page before, you can see the page again. That's just how computers work! I've used some internet banking sites that claim to disable the back button in the browser, but this is just ridiculous and is very easy to circumvent. If someone at a public computer leaves their browser open without logging off, that's a user error!

Comment: @ChrisCohen - Google mail has this feature! Yahoo mail also does it! My question was just how to do it in Drupal...

Comment: @indrock Oops, I started to write something and realised it was nonsense so I stopped...didn't realise it had submitted!

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the user from looking at the cache of his own browser.  And you should not even try.  Breaking the browser's navigation paradigm is not a recommended practice.

Having said that, there are tricks you can use to make it appear as if the back button is disabled.  Users can get around those tricks, but you may fool some of the people some of the time.

Here is one page that explains those tricks: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

Searching with Google for "Disable back button" will give you a lot more.

To add js to your site, look up [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in the API.

Answer (score 1):

Its too late but I came with a perfect solution. I have written a module [Back Button Refresh](http://drupal.org/project/bbr).

**Configuration**

Install the module as regular process then configure Back Button Refresh block visibility settings in Home » Administration » Structure » Blocks

- Search Back Button Refresh block and set it to bottom region of your default theme. If admin theme is different then do the block settings for all of your theme you are using and has user restricted data so that this block must be available on your sensitive pages.
- Set visibility of block to display on all pages.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in a custom module :

```
<?php 
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function MY_MODULE_init() {
  drupal_add_http_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
}
?>
```