# How do I disable the Back button after logout?

Tags: quiz, users

I have created a quiz portal using Drupal. The issue is that, after logout, one can easily go back by pressing the browser's Back button. It is improper when someone takes a quiz and leaves the browser open. Then, another user can easily get the previous result just by pressing the Back button.

I want to disable the Back button after logout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Although same question is posted here also, but I dint get desired answer, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27358/after-logging-off-a-user-is-able-to-see-the-pages-by-pressing-back-button-of-th

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  And you should not even try.  Breaking the browser's navigation paradigm is not a recommended practice.

Having said that, there are tricks you can use to make it appear as if the back button is disabled.  Users can get around those tricks, but you may fool some of the people some of the time.

Here is one page that explains those tricks: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/disable-back-button-browser-javascript/

Google will give you a lot more.

To add js to your site, look up [drupal_add_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) in the API.

Comment: Hi Gisle, Thanks for quick reply. Please tell me, how and where to insert that script. I am working on DRUPAL.